# Is this use of preposition 'bar' correct?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know whether the preposition *bar* in the following sentence is correct, meaning "except for". Its usage is not very clear to me from Oxford's and Cambridge's dictionaries and I could really use some native opinion on the subject.

*He is always glad to see them, bar their sharp-tongued remarks.*

Comment: Hello, afk. Even using 'except for' here wouldn't be so good. I'll amend your example: 'He admires everything about them, except for their sharp-tongued remarks.' You could certainly substitute 'bar' here, but it wouldn't be nearly as idiomatic. 'Bar' in this sense tends to be used fairly rarely outside horse-racing; 'It was all over bar the shouting', as a fixed expression, constitutes an exception.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Horse-racing? Katy bar the door!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "bar none" is also frequently used.

Comment: "Bar is usually followed by terseness. Not flowery phrases", she said naively.

Comment: Barring their sharp-tongued comments, he was always glad to see them.

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to know whether the preposition [use of] bar in the [posted]
>   sentence is correct, meaning "except for"?

**bar**  Three definitions/uses to *support* the sense of 'bar = except' all using **bar** as a preposition (non-idiomatic uses):

1. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bar)

> **except for** (prep)

As in:

> That was the best recital, **bar** last night's.

2. as a preposition  [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bar)

> preposition **EXCEPT**

As in:
​

> He’s the greatest pitcher of all time, bar none.

3. as a preposition  [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bar)

> **Except for**

As in:

> ‘His kids were all gone now, **bar** one’